# traverse through nested children of an array of objects and make a property equals false - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a tree, that I want to traverse through. I want to make each `internalChecked = false`. I wrote some code, but failed.

**Tree**

```js
let json = [
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Steel",
    "value": 2,
    "internalChildren": [
      {
        "internalDisabled": false,
        "internalChecked": true,
        "internalCollapsed": false,
        "text": "Cars",
        "value": 54,
        "internalChildren": [
          {
            "internalDisabled": false,
            "internalChecked": true,
            "internalCollapsed": false,
            "text": "Sedan",
            "value": 55,
            "internalChildren": [
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "test",
                "value": 1053
              },
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "cc cc cc",
                "value": 1054,
                "internalChildren": [
                  {
                    "internalDisabled": false,
                    "internalChecked": true,
                    "internalCollapsed": false,
                    "text": "cccccc",
                    "value": 1055
                  },
                  {
                    "internalDisabled": false,
                    "internalChecked": true,
                    "internalCollapsed": false,
                    "text": "xxxxxxx",
                    "value": 1056
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "internalDisabled": false,
            "internalChecked": true,
            "internalCollapsed": false,
            "text": "train",
            "value": 2053,
            "internalChildren": [
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "bullet",
                "value": 2054
              },
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "pessenger",
                "value": 2055
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Auto/Boat",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Build Your Own Job",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Cleaning & Housekeeping",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Delivery & Courier",
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Handyman",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Hourly Help",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Lawn & Yard",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Moving",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Organization",
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Painting",
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Pet Care",
    "value": 14
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "TV Mount & Electronics",
    "value": 15
  }
];


//CODE
let savedIndex
let outPut= []
let savedJson = json

function traverseArray(__json, __index){
    for (let i = 0; i < __json.length; i++) {
        const _item = __json[i];
        _item.internalChecked = false
        outPut.push({
            ..._item
        })
        if(_item.internalChildren && _item.internalChildren.length > 0){
            savedIndex = __index
            traverseArray(_item.internalChildren, i)
        }
    }
    return outPut
}

console.log(traverseArray(json, 0))
```

Comment: Try to edit the snippets to work when you press "Run code snippet". Right now you have 2 different snippets instead of one with all the code embedded. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you :P EDIT: Someone already done it for you.

Comment: Your code works fine

Comment: but cant traverse children and make the property false

Comment: I'm not sure what savedIndex is (you're setting it to __index, but neither of those variables are used anywhere), but otherwise your code looks fine and produces the correct output (all nodes and all children have internalChecked = false). Note: objects are passed by reference, not value, so when you're manipulating the properties of them, you're changing the original objects directly. Therefore, you don't need to make the copy of the array `outPut` -- the original array will be updated with your changes automatically.

Comment: I just need to traverse all those `internalChecked`to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing every json chunk in an output array that makes the output different than it is, just use `__json[i].internalChecked = false` in your loop and it will update the array on which you are iterating on:

```js
let json = [ { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Steel", "value": 2, "internalChildren": [ { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "Cars", "value": 54, "internalChildren": [ { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "Sedan", "value": 55, "internalChildren": [ { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "test", "value": 1053 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "cc cc cc", "value": 1054, "internalChildren": [ { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "cccccc", "value": 1055 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "xxxxxxx", "value": 1056 } ] } ] }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "train", "value": 2053, "internalChildren": [ { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "bullet", "value": 2054 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": false, "text": "pessenger", "value": 2055 } ] } ] } ] }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Auto/Boat", "value": 3 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Build Your Own Job", "value": 4 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Cleaning & Housekeeping", "value": 5 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Delivery & Courier", "value": 6 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Handyman", "value": 7 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Hourly Help", "value": 8 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Lawn & Yard", "value": 10 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Moving", "value": 11 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Organization", "value": 12 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Painting", "value": 13 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "Pet Care", "value": 14 }, { "internalDisabled": false, "internalChecked": true, "internalCollapsed": true, "text": "TV Mount & Electronics", "value": 15 } ];


let savedIndex
let savedJson = json

function traverseArray(__json, __index){
    for (let i = 0; i < __json.length; i++) {
        __json[i].internalChecked = false
        if (__json[i].internalChildren) {
            savedIndex = __index
            traverseArray(__json[i].internalChildren, i)
        }
    }
    return savedJson
}

console.log("original length:: ", json.length);
const output = traverseArray(savedJson, 0);
console.log("output length:: ", output.length);
 
console.log("output:: ", output);
```

Also, if clause,

```
if (__json[i].internalChildren && __json[i].internalChildren.length > 0)
```

can be simply

```
if (__json[i].internalChildren)
```

Comment: check, that the original array length is 13 and the output is 22

Comment: @NadeemAhmad hope this is what you need. Enjoy, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution, not the best for efficiency as it could be made tail recursive.

```js
let json = [
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Steel",
    "value": 2,
    "internalChildren": [
      {
        "internalDisabled": false,
        "internalChecked": true,
        "internalCollapsed": false,
        "text": "Cars",
        "value": 54,
        "internalChildren": [
          {
            "internalDisabled": false,
            "internalChecked": true,
            "internalCollapsed": false,
            "text": "Sedan",
            "value": 55,
            "internalChildren": [
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "test",
                "value": 1053
              },
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "cc cc cc",
                "value": 1054,
                "internalChildren": [
                  {
                    "internalDisabled": false,
                    "internalChecked": true,
                    "internalCollapsed": false,
                    "text": "cccccc",
                    "value": 1055
                  },
                  {
                    "internalDisabled": false,
                    "internalChecked": true,
                    "internalCollapsed": false,
                    "text": "xxxxxxx",
                    "value": 1056
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "internalDisabled": false,
            "internalChecked": true,
            "internalCollapsed": false,
            "text": "train",
            "value": 2053,
            "internalChildren": [
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "bullet",
                "value": 2054
              },
              {
                "internalDisabled": false,
                "internalChecked": true,
                "internalCollapsed": false,
                "text": "pessenger",
                "value": 2055
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Auto/Boat",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Build Your Own Job",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Cleaning & Housekeeping",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Delivery & Courier",
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Handyman",
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Hourly Help",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Lawn & Yard",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Moving",
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Organization",
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Painting",
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "Pet Care",
    "value": 14
  },
  {
    "internalDisabled": false,
    "internalChecked": true,
    "internalCollapsed": true,
    "text": "TV Mount & Electronics",
    "value": 15
  }
];


//CODE
let savedIndex
let outPut= []
let savedJson = json

function traverseArray(arr){
    try{
      arr.forEach((obj) => {
        if(obj.internalChecked){
           obj.internalChecked = false
        }
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((k)=>{
          if(obj[k].length>1){
              traverseArray(obj[k]);
           }
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      if(arr.internalChecked){
           arr.internalChecked = false
       }
    }
      
}

traverseArray(json);
console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive method `getTraversedArray` using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const json = [{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Steel',value: 2,internalChildren: [{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'Cars',value: 54,internalChildren: [{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'Sedan',value: 55,internalChildren: [{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'test',value: 1053,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'cc cc cc',value: 1054,internalChildren: [{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'cccccc',value: 1055,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'xxxxxxx',value: 1056,},],},],},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'train',value: 2053,internalChildren: [{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'bullet',value: 2054,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: false,text: 'pessenger',value: 2055,},],},],},],},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Auto/Boat',value: 3,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Build Your Own Job',value: 4,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Cleaning & Housekeeping',value: 5,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Delivery & Courier',value: 6,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Handyman',value: 7,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Hourly Help',value: 8,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Lawn & Yard',value: 10,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Moving',value: 11,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Organization',value: 12,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Painting',value: 13,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'Pet Care',value: 14,},{internalDisabled: false,internalChecked: true,internalCollapsed: true,text: 'TV Mount & Electronics',value: 15,},]

const getTraversedArray = (json) => json.map(o => {
  o.internalChecked = false
  if (Array.isArray(o.internalChildren)) {
    o.internalChildren = getTraversedArray(o.internalChildren)
  }
  return o
})

console.log(getTraversedArray(json))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and take a copy from the object.

```js
function traverseArray(array) {
    return array.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { internalChecked: false },
        o.internalChildren && { internalChildren: traverseArray(o.internalChildren) }
    ));
}

let data = [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Steel", value: 2, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "Cars", value: 54, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "Sedan", value: 55, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "test", value: 1053 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "cc cc cc", value: 1054, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "cccccc", value: 1055 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "xxxxxxx", value: 1056 }] }] }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "train", value: 2053, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "bullet", value: 2054 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: "pessenger", value: 2055 }] }] }] }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Auto/Boat", value: 3 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Build Your Own Job", value: 4 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Cleaning & Housekeeping", value: 5 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Delivery & Courier", value: 6 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Handyman", value: 7 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Hourly Help", value: 8 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Lawn & Yard", value: 10 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Moving", value: 11 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Organization", value: 12 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Painting", value: 13 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "Pet Care", value: 14 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: "TV Mount & Electronics", value: 15 }];

console.log(traverseArray(data, 0));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme) this is pretty straight forward:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const modify = (data) => objectScan(['**.internalChecked'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
    parent[property] = false;
  }
})(data);

const json = [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Steel', value: 2, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'Cars', value: 54, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'Sedan', value: 55, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'test', value: 1053 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'cc cc cc', value: 1054, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'cccccc', value: 1055 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'xxxxxxx', value: 1056 }] }] }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'train', value: 2053, internalChildren: [{ internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'bullet', value: 2054 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'pessenger', value: 2055 }] }] }] }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Auto/Boat', value: 3 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Build Your Own Job', value: 4 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Cleaning & Housekeeping', value: 5 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Delivery & Courier', value: 6 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Handyman', value: 7 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Hourly Help', value: 8 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Lawn & Yard', value: 10 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Moving', value: 11 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Organization', value: 12 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Painting', value: 13 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Pet Care', value: 14 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: true, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'TV Mount & Electronics', value: 15 }];

console.log(modify(json)); // returns number of matches
// => 22

console.log(json);
// => [ { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Steel', value: 2, internalChildren: [ { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'Cars', value: 54, internalChildren: [ { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'Sedan', value: 55, internalChildren: [ { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'test', value: 1053 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'cc cc cc', value: 1054, internalChildren: [ { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'cccccc', value: 1055 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'xxxxxxx', value: 1056 } ] } ] }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'train', value: 2053, internalChildren: [ { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'bullet', value: 2054 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: false, text: 'pessenger', value: 2055 } ] } ] } ] }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Auto/Boat', value: 3 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Build Your Own Job', value: 4 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Cleaning & Housekeeping', value: 5 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Delivery & Courier', value: 6 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Handyman', value: 7 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Hourly Help', value: 8 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Lawn & Yard', value: 10 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Moving', value: 11 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Organization', value: 12 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Painting', value: 13 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'Pet Care', value: 14 }, { internalDisabled: false, internalChecked: false, internalCollapsed: true, text: 'TV Mount & Electronics', value: 15 } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)